# How to debug a Chrome CRX that does not start?

Tags: debugging, apk, google-chrome-app

I have built a CRX from an APK. When I run in in Chrome, all I get is this:

[image: CRX puzzled]

- The OS menu does not have any clickable item or anything
- Clicking and right clicking does nothing
- I tried starting the app from a tab with a JavaScript console, but the tab gets closed as soon as I click to start the app.

**QUESTION:** How can I debug the app or at least get a few hints about what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Some info can be logged by starting Chrome this way:

```
CHROME_LOG_FILE=chrome.log google-chrome --enable-logging --log-level=0
```

Info will appear both:

- in the console output
- in the specified log file

To produce more verbose logging, place this JSON file besides the APK before converting it (name it `<name-of-the-apk>.crx.json`:

```
{
    "stderrLog": "V"
}
```